# How to Expand/Collapse Primefaces fieldset using jquery?

Tags: jquery, primefaces, fieldset

I'm using primefaces 3.5 and I have a p:fieldset and a p:commandbutton,
I'm able to toggle the fieldset using the button using it's client side api method

```
oncomplete="detailsFieldset.toggle()"
```

but I'd like to only Expand the fieldset if it's collapsed not the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

`oncomplete="if($(detailsFieldset.toggleStateHolder).attr('value') === 'true'){det`ailsFieldset.toggle();}"

`toggleStateHolder` holds the state of the collapsed mode... so when its value is `true` it means that the `p:fieldset` (or any other pf collapsible element) is collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

Modified the above solution by Daniel

```
oncomplete="if($(detailsFieldset.toggleStateHolder).attr('value') === 'true'){detailsFieldset.toggle();}"
```

to

```
oncomplete="if($(detailsFieldset.stateHolder).attr('value') === 'true'){detailsFieldset.toggle();}"
```

for it to work for me.